# Mongodb Array Update

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I have following mongodb json.I would like to update price of  product_id:2 from 4 to 5 in the document with document _id:id1
Can someone guide me how to do that in mongodb or using c#

```
{
    "_id": "id1",
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": "pr1",
            "price":1,
            "qty":5
        },
        {
            "product_id": "pr2",
            "price":4,
            "qty":10
        },
        {
            "product_id": "pr3",
            "price":8,
            "qty":9
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the C# mongodb driver from mondodb site.

```
var collection = DataBase.GetCollection<MyProducts>("products");
var query = Query<MyProduct>.Where(p => (m.productID == "pr2"));

var product = collection.FindOne(query);
product.Price = 5;
collection.Save(product);
```

Comment: Well, the Database is new MongoClient(url)).GetServer()

Comment: any light on <MyProudcts> and m.productID ?

Comment: This is a class which represents your mongodb entity. Create One, according your json in your example. Than you will be able to create the class instance with data, and you can read/write data to mondo.

Comment: So, what exactly does not work? What did you do? What is exception? Please, see the C# driver manual, here is the what you need: http://ru.docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#getting-started-with-csharp-driver

Answer (score 0):

Either use the .update function in mongo db or pull the object out using linq something like:

```
 var query = (from c in Collection.AsQueryable<T>() where c.Id == Id select c).First<T>();
```

adjusting the above variables accordingly.

Then changing whatever that object is then saving it using Collection.Save(obj) this will re write the whole object. Look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/ and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/